# How to run integration tests in UAT where the output is a jms message to a queue consumed by another service?

Tags: java, spring, jms, integration-testing

Does anyone know how to verify an output in an end-to-end test where this is a message to a queue?

I'm running an application that relies on 3 different services. I would like to run an end-to-end test that uses REST as entry points and jms queues as outputs. The environment where this runs is UAT and I don't have control over the broker configuration. These output messages are sent to another service outside of the scope of this test so I won't be able to mock the consumer as this needs to be the real one. The test would be run from a separate project pulled from a CI job.

With this situation, is there any way I can verify that, given an input, I get an output in the form of a jms message without interfering with the normal behavior of the environment? I was told I could use the Wiretap pattern but I'm not using any integration framework, just plain Spring JmsTemplate so I would have to kind of duplicate the message myself. Besides, for this, as far as I understand, the message would need to be sent to another queue I can listen to so it would need to be created for this tests.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an in-memory ActiveMQ instance specifically for UAT and submit messages there and then do your validation.  I've done it before, it's somewhat a pain, but it does give you complete control over your UAT environment without being subject to the whims of your infrastructure/admins/whatever.

Comment: But doing that i would only test one component,not the communication across the 3 of them as the emdedded broker would run locally to the instance.besides,my understanding is that with that approach i would need to provide profiles or something similar to control whether i'm running a test,requiring to restart the application when the test has finished.that or leave backdoors in the code for testing

Comment: Yeah, correct, I was thinking "unit" tests not "user acceptance" when I first read it...I'd still try and get an instance specific to UAT that you can have control over rather than use a centralized service that might impact how you execute tests...